# How to inherit component palette icons (*.dcr files) for custom components?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, c++builder

In the past, I have written custom components for Borland C++Builder. Some of these were derived from existing components, for example:

```
class PACKAGE TMyEdit : public TEdit
{
   ...
}
```

For some of these, I have also made custom bitmaps for the palette (`.dcr` files). I know how to create and edit them; that's not the point here.

Nowadays, I'm using a newer version of the IDE, Embarcadero C++Builder XE, and I notice a difference in behaviour for components without a `.dcr` file.

In the old days, the bitmap on the palette would be the same as the one where the component was derived from. Let's say the `TMyEdit` had the same bitmap as the `TEdit`.

But now, these components get a default icon. So all components without a `.dcr` file look alike on the palette.

I see 2 possible ways to solve this:

1. Is there perhaps some way to indicate in the source files that I want to inherit the bitmap of the original component?
2. If that isn't possible, I'll have to create new `.dcr` files for each new component. Is there a neat way to retrieve the original bitmaps? Perhaps there exists a resource file? Or an option in a wizard that I haven't found yet? If not, I'll have to resort to using <kbd>Alt-PrtScn</kbd> and MSPaint. That would work, but it would be tedious.